# How to NAT private IP to public IP through virtual LAN in centos 6

Tags: centos, nat, masquerade

Guys i am having an issue with NAT on centos. In my LAB Centos is configured as a router. I want to run my local system (**example: 192.168.1.45**) apache server on live IP (**example 112.100.4.34**).

This is already done by another user but i am unable to do it.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done via post-routing table and masquerade:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

previous rule will nat all traffic trough the eth0 interface and change the source address (if that is the interface with the public ip address.) if you want to nat a single ip:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -src 192.168.1.45 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 112.100.4.34
```

If you want to persistent the previously rule add the rule removing `iptables` prefix in to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file of your centos.

To have a detail of the iptables rules take a read [here](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/it/NAT-HOWTO-6.html)